# Wordpress additional css won't change the margin of my row

Tags: css, wordpress, mobile

I'm quite new to website design, currently I'm using the Plugin "Simple CSS" to add css to my site and make it mobile-friendly   e.G:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .seperator {  
        display: none;
    }
    .row_01 {  
        margin-left: 0px;
    }
}
```

to get rid of unneccessary content on mobile and to reorder/replace elements. In this case the margin of the row won't change. The surrounding container does not have a margin either. Something else like

```
display: none;
```

would apply to the row, but obviously that's not what i want. Also adding

```
!important
```

has no effect. I'm using the "The7" WP-theme, maybe this is important. What am I missing?

Comment: Try using inheritance of the classes you are targeting. i.e for example class .seperator, look for its inheritance in the original css it is declared. They try using the same inheritance in your customization.

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear cache.. Try to ctrl + f5(if you use windows)

Comment: did not help :(

Answer (score 0):

try to change the default load priority of the css file from the plugin :

```
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', function() {
    remove_action( 'wp_head', 'simple_css_generate' );
    add_action( 'wp_head', 'simple_css_generate', 999);
} );
```

Set your priority at max so the CSS loads latest at your head.

Comment: how can I edit the plugin? I also don't think that it will help, because - as I said - other modifications will apply (eG editing margins of a textField within the row)

Comment: add this in your functions.php, the point is this css to be applied after all your css files loaded from your theme.

Answer (score 0):

```
@media all and (max-width: 768px)
```

Comment: sadly did not chance anything either